# Plotting Bessel function in MATLAB

Tags: math, matlab, bessel-functions

In MATLAB how do you plot

f(r) = { 2*J1(a*r) / r }^2

where a = 2*pi
and J1 is Bessel function of the 1st kind
and r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

This should plot in 3D, i.e. kind of be like a bubble (not sure how to do this)

Answer (score 10):

Use [**besselj**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/besselj.html) --- the Bessel function of first kind --- to generate `J1`. I suppose you have to vary `a` and `r` to generate the "bubble".

I generated the following by varying `x` and `y` from `-1:0.01:1` and plotting meshing points `(x,y,f)`, I don't know if this is what you want.

#### Code

```
a = 2*pi;
[X Y] = meshgrid(-1:0.01:1,-1:0.01:1);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);
f = (2*besselj(1,a*R(:))./R(:)).^2;
mesh(X,Y,reshape(f,size(X)));
axis vis3d;
```

#### Log plot

Doresdoom suggestion, I replaced `axis vis3d;` with `set(gca,'Zscale','Log')`.

[image]

#### Mesh

[image]

Comment: use `set(gca,'Zscale','Log')` instead of `axis vis3d` to get the 'bubble' effect

Comment: +1 - really nice job here.  Worth an upvote just for the asthetic quality of the contour plots.

Comment: @duffymo: Yeah they are beautiful, but it's all thanks to MATLAB :)

Comment: @Jacob - last time I checked, MATLAB didn't run itself.  Still requires a smart, motivated person to tell it what to do.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make the little oscillations at the base more pronounced? When I do it it looks basically flat when I graph. Also, how do you make the graph look different, for example plot it so that it is uniformly green or something or alternatively so you just see the gridlines?

Comment: Did you check out the `besselj` function? I set the first variable to `1` for this demo but you should probably take a closer look. And you make it uniformly green with `mesh(X,Y,reshape(f,size(X)),ones(size(X)))`

Comment: I think we have the bubble :)

Comment: Hi I need to plot E=(2*(besselj(1,ka*sind(theta))))/(ka*sind(theta); where "ka" is a constant. and theta varies. above is the expression for energy transmitted from a flat circular piston. Can you help?

Comment: anybody know how can I plot forier transform of bessel?